# Are there any more operators like ~ when querying data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I notice the '~' sign in the firebase documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByKey().startAt("b").endAt("b~").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

are there other expressions like '~' that can be use in firebase? I'm curious if there's a operator that acts like `.contains(string)` rather than fetching all then filter the data. I'm trying to keep my self away from elastic search.

Comment: The tilde (`~`) is not any specific operator. It is just a character that happens to be higher in the ASCII chart than all others that are used in the `key`. Similarly you could use a space or bang (`!`) as a character that is early in the ASCII chart: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as `.contains` in the Firebase API.

Your best bet is to write a utility function which fetches the data and filters it for you.