# How to Perform Search Operation on Value in Firebase? AngularJS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say example, I have 4 users with email addresses:

```
hello@world.com
hi@world.com 
yo@world.com
yeah@world.com
```

This is my search query from view

```
$scope.searchQuery = "h";
```

I run this query which allows me to get a list of user with the email address that start with letter "h".

```
usersRef.orderByChild('email').startAt($scope.searchQuery).endAt($scope.searchQuery+"~").on('value', function(snapshot){
      console.log(snapshot.val());
}
```

So, the results in here are:

```
hello@world.com
hi@world.com
```

However, I'd like the searchQuery to match the whole string, not just the start with letters. 
The expected results in this case are ($searchQuery = "h"):

```
hello@world.com
hi@world.com
yeah@world.com
```

I've tried this:

```
usersRef.orderByChild('email').startAt($scope.searchQuery).endAt("~"+$scope.searchQuery+"~").on('value', function(snapshot){
          console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
```

The results includes all 4 email addresses.

Then, I've tried this:

```
usersRef.orderByChild('email').startAt("~"+$scope.searchQuery).endAt($scope.searchQuery+"~").on('value', function(snapshot){
              console.log(snapshot.val());
        }
```

The result was null.

Can someone help me to figure this out please.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Firebase Queries do not have a contains operation. Also `~` is not a wildcard operator. It is just a character that happens to be high in the ASCII range. So `startAt('a').endAt('a~')` is *almost* the same as `startAt('a').endAt('b')`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any more operators like ~ when querying data in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702852/are-there-any-more-operators-like-when-querying-data-in-firebase)