# Searching on custom string keys in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m experimenting with custom keys in Firebase and wanted to get advice on this setup. Here I have this list of string keys in the `ADDRESS_ID` (see code below) and I want to search among them.

Lets say I know I have this address:
(the (fss) is a forward slash)

Firebase key:

```
 "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1600 pennsylvania ave nw"
```

and I want to find every key that at least have the

```
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw"
```

That means I want to find all addresses on "pennsylvania ave nw" right..

The query should then return this right:(see code below)

```
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1606 pennsylvania ave nw"
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1605 pennsylvania ave nw"
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1603 pennsylvania ave nw"
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1600 pennsylvania ave nw"
```

How should I construct the query?

The reason I do it like this with custom keys is because searching for addresses is going to happen allot. As you see every key holds the pushkey for and "ADDRESSES" (see code below). Searching on the much larger "ADDRESSES" will be costly right

Is this a good way or should I reconsider because of my query is impossible or costly dunno. Hope you see what I get at. I´m doing Firebase for 4 month only and like it allot because of the great Firebase codelabs

```
"ADDRESS_ID" : {
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1600 pennsylvania ave nw" : {
        "-KZhVUg43lazrLQbIuLJ" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1600 pennsylvania ave se" : {
        "-KZs0G5-FP3QW3MeoWre" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1602 pennsylvania ave se" : {
        "-KZrzqjDosglsZBmu46M" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1603 pennsylvania ave nw" : {
        "-K_BKBS_xwjmE_n_gG7A" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1604 pennsylvania ave se" : {
        "-K_BKKeQQe4Kb4xi6RWo" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1605 pennsylvania ave nw" : {
        "-K_Dq0W4-BXeAJaoq0MT" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1606 pennsylvania ave nw" : {
        "-K_EFIVvcjfga3oILx9Q" : "true"
      },
      "US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)1607 pennsylvania ave se" : {
        "-K_DtORcp-In3LqxYJSU" : "true"
      }
    },
```

for reference:

```
"US" : {
    "ADDRESSES" : {
      "-KZhVUg43lazrLQbIuLJ" : {
        "lat" : 38.8976758,
        "legacy" : "HnhLyXRxUINmlltKOfxx2QBYiQ53",
        "lng" : -77.0364823,
        "path" : "US/district of columbia/washington/1600 pennsylvania ave nw",
        "placeId" : "ChIJ437B3ry3t4kRRV7Us0ixIPk",
        "pushId" : "-KZhVUg43lazrLQbIuLJ",
        "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington,+DC+20500,+USA&ftid=0x89b7b7bcdec17ee3:0xf920b148b3d45e45"
      },
      "-KZrzqjDosglsZBmu46M" : {
        "lat" : 38.89871249999999,
        "legacy" : "HnhLyXRxUINmlltKOfxx2QBYiQ53",
        "lng" : -77.0377377,
        "path" : "US/district of columbia/washington/1602 pennsylvania ave nw",
        "placeId" : "ChIJcTGziry3t4kR66DS_AYdhrg",
        "pushId" : "-KZrzqjDosglsZBmu46M",
        "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=1602+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington,+DC+20500,+USA&ftid=0x89b7b7bc8ab33171:0xb8861d06fcd2a0eb"
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can only select specific nodes that are equal or nodes that start with a specific value. That's why we typically refer to them as "range queries": they select a range of nodes.

Your current keys don't allow for selecting of a range of addresses. The reason is that you have the number of the address before the street name, while apparently you want to select a range of numbers in a street (or even the entire street).

To allow the query you want, you should separate the number from the street name. So:

```
"US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw(fss)1600"
```

With a data structure like this, you can select everyone on `pennsylvania ave nw` with:

```
ref.startAt("US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw(fss)")
   .endAt("US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw(fss)")
```

You could even get a range of numbers with:

```
ref.startAt("US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw(fss)1600")
   .endAt("US(fss)district of columbia(fss)washington(fss)pennsylvania ave nw(fss)1700")
```

Comment: Thanks looks good but the `startsWith` is not a a Firebase keyword can you elaborate?

Comment: Ah... `startAt`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: Thanks this was grate, when I use ´startAt(... ave nw(fss)"))´ it gives me all addresses on that street but when also using startAt and endAt together as you describe gives nothing. Yea great solution adding street nummer at the end.

Comment: If you're having problems making the code work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The easiest way to do so is by creating a jsbin, which allows us to see exactly what you see.

Comment: I like a comment on this - I could only make this work by doing like this `startAt(... ave nw(fss)")` ... `endAt(... ave nw(fss)~")` ,,,notice the ~ .
That will give me what you write in your answer - "With a data structure like this, you can select everyone on pennsylvania ave nw with:". 
I´m I doing this the correct way or did I find an Easter-egg :)

Comment: The `~` is no magic operator. It just happens to be the last character in the ASCII range, which makes it useful for range queries on ASCII values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702852/are-there-any-more-operators-like-when-querying-data-in-firebase. We nowadays actually recommend an equally high value in the Unicode range.