# How to do wildcard string search for a field in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to implement a string search in Firebase database similar to SQL query:

```
SELECT select_column from table_name where search_column LIKE '%search_word%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase itself does not support text search. The closest you can achieve with a query is a partial string match using this hack:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(table_name).orderByChild(select_column).startAt(search_word).endAt(search_word + "~");
```

The `~` character [has the highest ASCII value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29702852/213156) of any printable character, so the result of the query is all cases of `select_column` that begin with `search_word`.

If you need more advanced searching or matching criteria you'll have to use or write a full text search solution. [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) is a popular one with Firebase. [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) is a Node.js module that merges the two directly in the database. (Note that it may now be possible to deploy Flashlight to [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) instead of the recommended Heroku configuration.)

Comment: How can we do the Opposite? Search cases where it ends on the searchword?

Comment: @user1007522 As in `orderByChild(select_column).endAt(search_word)`? That gives you everything that comes before the search alphabetically but it's not exactly a text match.